# Deploying Python scripts with Eclipse

Tags: python, eclipse, deployment

I have written some Python scripts in Eclipse where at some point I have stable releases which should be deployed. For the moment this is very simple and means copying the scripts to some directory. (Soon I will also consider Git)

Could you tell me the common extendable way to set up a process like this in Eclipse? Maybe something more professional which, if a more complicating deployment becomes neccessary, can still be used.

(I had seen Ant somewhere, but I'm not sure if that is more than I need and maybe not the convention for Python in particular).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say use [Fabric](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.4.2/index.html), and read [this blog post](http://www.clemesha.org/blog/modern-python-hacker-tools-virtualenv-fabric-pip/) for a reasonable introduction to it.